# Count object in Tab Separated Array in Python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have an array of integer `r = [ 242  302  377 ..., 1090  225  203]`. I would like to count the occurrences of `242` in `r` array. I used the count method like this:

```
asd = r.count(242)
print asd
```

but it gives me error

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'count'.

How to solve this?

Comment: separating the values of the array with comma (,) may work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to understand:

```
my_count = 0
for i in r:
    if (i == 242):
        my_count += 1
print my_count
```

Answer (score 1):

Can try below code to compute -

Type 1-

```
r = [ 451, 242, 300, 424, 242, 567, 810, 242, 151, 413]

n= [i for i in r if i == 242]

print(len(n))
```

Type 2-

```
count = 0
r = [ 451, 242, 300, 424, 242, 567, 810, 242, 151, 413]
for i in r:
   if i == 242:
      count+=1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Comma-separate your list values: `r = [ 242, 302, 242, 377, 1090, 225, 203]`:

```
r = [ 242, 302, 242, 377, 1090, 225, 203]

asd = r.count(242)

print asd
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a 'tab separated array'. The display of `r` is consistent with it being a `numpy array` (as is the error message). It may have been loaded from a tab separated CSV. In any case, `count` is a list method, not an array one. Either convert it to a list, or use one of the iterative solutions.

There is an array `bincount`.  Since your array appears to be integers in a reasonable range, e.g. 0-1000), it might apply here.

Make a sample array:

```
In [147]: r=np.random.randint(0,1000,2000)
In [148]: r
Out[148]: array([170, 754, 151, ..., 115, 299, 879])
```

Its `str` display is:

```
In [166]: print(r)
[170 754 151 ..., 115 299 879]
```

This probably confuses Python programmers who don't know about `numpy`.

`bincount` finds the count for all values in the range:

```
In [152]: np.bincount(r)
Out[152]: 
array([4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 4,
       ...
       1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3])
```

I probably should have used `np.bincount(r,minlength=1000)`.

The 7th value in that count list is `4`, so let's select that:

```
In [176]: np.bincount(r,minlength=1000)[6]
Out[176]: 4
```

I can use `count` if I first convert `r` to a list:

```
In [177]: r.tolist().count(6)
Out[177]: 4
```

The iterative solutions also work, but are slower:

```
def foo(a,v):
    my_count=0
    for i in r:
        if (i==v):
            my_count+=1
    return my_count

In [178]: foo(r,6)
Out[178]: 4
```

time tests:

```
In [180]: timeit foo(r,6)
1000 loops, best of 3: 983 us per loop

In [181]: timeit len([i for i in r if i==6])
1000 loops, best of 3: 985 us per loop

In [182]: timeit r.tolist().count(6)
10000 loops, best of 3: 125 us per loop

In [183]: timeit np.bincount(r)[6]
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.2 us per loop
```

Another good array version tests for `value` in one compiled expression.

```
In [189]: timeit (r==6).sum()
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.5 us per loop
```

To test for several values at once, use an expression like:

```
In [194]: (r==np.array([6,42,242])[:,None]).sum(axis=1)
Out[194]: array([4, 5, 1])
```

Answer (score -1):

**Simple example:**

If you get to work with a list type of a structure supporting `.count()` function you cann apply:

```
list.count(x)
```

where `list` is a type of a listable collection, `count()` is a function taking a single argument `x` which identifies which element to check for occurrences

Else you could try and apply something like:

```
counter = 0

for x in list:
    if x == 1:
        counter += 1

print('Counter: ', counter)
```

where `list` is a listable collection;

Comment: Could person who down-voted provide reason for the answer to be downvoted? I

Comment: Do you mean `iterable`?  `r.tolist().count(1)` might work.

Comment: There is no syntax issue in the code above; both solutions produce equal result. I would be interested to know why it has been downvoted. In fact, solution below, by @Dlucidone has same type of syntax.